# How Long Can I Keep Uncooked Sushi Rice?

Tags: storage-method, storage-lifetime, rice, sushi

I only prepare sushi rice a few times a year, so it takes me a while to go through even the smallest of bags.  How long can I keep the bag for before it "goes bad"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Keep it airtight in a cool, dark place and it should remain good infefinitely.  You'll certainly be fine 1-2 years.

Comment: Agreed. Make sure it is well sealed from critters (which I guess goes along with airtight), and you'll be fine.

Comment: Additional note: the same is *not* true of brown rice. It has enough fat left in the seed to go rancid. Take a deep whiff whenever you open a container, and if you detect even a hint of rancidity, dump it and buy fresh.