# how can I store uncooked rice

Tags: rice, storage

Should rice be stored in a sealed container in the refrigerator or should it be kept in a cabinet in sealed container?

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5749/how-long-can-i-keep-uncooked-sushi-rice?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Long Can I Keep Uncooked Sushi Rice?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5749/how-long-can-i-keep-uncooked-sushi-rice)

Answer (score 1):

Rice attracts quite a lot of moisture and may develop a moss-like smell in the longer run. Most of the rice that is used in India doesn't require airtight storage but shouldn't be exposed to moisture.

Some of the aromatic rice varieties such as Basmati are sealed and aged for perfection. These types of rice may lose their aroma if kept in the open air.

So if you are storing rice for long term use, keep in an airtight container.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store the uncooked rice (raw rice) in any cabinet, or airtight container. 
You can store it in any large container and keep it anywhere in your house. But there are chances that Rice weevils (rice insects) will infect your rice after 2 to 4 months.
So to prevent that, you can mix some boric acid powder. It will prevent from forming rice weevils.
But make sure before cooking, you wash the rice properly and then cook.

Answer (score 0):

For long-term (i.e. months to years) storage, the most common method is heat-sealed mylar bags, either with an oxygen absorber or vacuum sealed.